# Draw a line from points on same row of datafile

Tags: gnuplot

Normally, when plotting using lines, gnuplot connects points defined by subsequent rows of a datafile. However, my datafile is of the form

```
x1  y1  x2  y2
x1  y1  x2  y2
x1  y1  x2  y2
...
```

and I want to connect every two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) of one row of the datafile by a line. I.e., the result should be n lines, each comprising two points, where n is the number of lines in the file.

**Question:** Is this (easily) achievable using gnuplot?

**Attempt:** I now that that this isn't the way gnuplot normally deals with datafiles. Of course, I can somehow transpose my datafile using awk or something like that. However, I would hope that there is an easier approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`vectors`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node259.html) plotting style:

```
plot 'your_data_file.dat' w vectors nohead lc rgb 'black'
```

Here, `nohead` specified that the rendered vectors won't contain an arrow tip...

Comment: Note, vectors needs *x y xdelta ydelta* so the OP probably needs `using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors`